# Efficiently read a CSV from an HTTP::Response

Tags: ruby

I would like to read a CSV with headers from an an [HTTP::Response::Body](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/http/HTTP/Response/Body) without pulling the entire contents into memory.

`CSV.new` takes a `String` or `IO`. Right now I'm having to turn the response body into a `String`, pulling it all into memory, before parsing the whole thing.

```
CSV.new(response.body.to_s, headers: true).each do |row|
    ...
end
```

Can I read and parse the response body line-by-line instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this benchmarking: https://dalibornasevic.com/posts/68-processing-large-csv-files-with-ruby

The memory usage/footprint from reading from IO is minimal and optimised using `CSV.new`.

Have you thought about using `open-uri` to read the remote file/http endpoint and stream to `CSV.new`?

Something like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.new(open('https://somesite/data.csv'))

while row = csv.shift # parse one by one with minimal memory footprint
  puts row.inspect
end
```

Comment: Yes, this query is simple enough that I can use `open-uri`. Thank you!